# How to check domain in laravel for some routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need check domain for some routes. Then after check, I need redirect domain `https://two.com` to `https://one.com` with `middleware` in laravel.

For example:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
Route::get('termsAndCondition', ['as' => 'termsAndCondition', 'uses' => 'IndexController@termsAndCondition']);
Route::get('aboutUs', ['as' => 'aboutUs', 'uses' => 'IndexController@aboutUs']);
Route::get('privacy', ['as' => 'privacy', 'uses' => 'IndexController@privacy']);
```

I need check `aboutUs` and `privacy` for domain name.

If domain name is `https://two.com/aboutUs` or `https://two.com/privacy` redirect to `https://one.com/aboutUs` or `https://one.com/privacy`.

I need check with middleware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this in a middleware:

```
if (request()->getHttpHost() === 'two.com' && in_array(request()->path(), ['aboutUs', 'privacy'])) {
    return redirect('https://one.com/' . request()->path());
}
```

Comment: I'm so stoked, that Laravel still doesn't have a better way, than `::macro`ing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can check url segments using `segment()` helper something like:

```
if(Request::segment(1)==='aboutus')
{

    return redirect(route('your other route');

}
if(Request::segment(1)==='privacy')
{

    return redirect(route('your other route');

}
```

You can add that check in your middleware, `segment()` expects an integer param like in case above 1 will check first wildcard after domain name.